# Does docker work correctly in a Ubuntu guest virtual machine of VMware Workstation?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, docker

I want to try docker and learn it. My host system is Windows 10, and I already have VMware Workstation installed. To use docker on Windows, I have to enable Hyper-V, which is incompatible with Vmware Workstation. There are ways to mitigate this problem, but I plan to go another way. Since I already have Vmware Workstation installed and I created a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS guest machine. I want to confirm if docker works as expected in this Ubuntu guest VM. Below is my configuration. Thanks.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                             |
|               My Windows 10 host machine                                    |
|                                                                             |
|    +-------------------------------------------------------------------+    |
|    | VMware Workstation                                                |    |
|    |                                                                   |    |
|    | +--------------------------------------+  +---------------------+ |    |
|    | |     Ubuntu 18.04 LTS                 |  | Another Windows VM  | |    |
|    | |                                      |  |                     | |    |
|    | |                                      |  |                     | |    |
|    | | +----------------------------------+ |  |                     | |    |
|    | | |   Docker                         | |  |                     | |    |
|    | | |                                  | |  |                     | |    |
|    | | | +-------------+ +-------------+  | |  |                     | |    |
|    | | | | Container 1 | | Container 2 |  | |  |                     | |    |
|    | | | +-------------+ +-------------+  | |  |                     | |    |
|    | | +----------------------------------+ |  |                     | |    |
|    | +--------------------------------------+  +---------------------+ |    |
|    +-------------------------------------------------------------------+    |
|                                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: [Are you asking if you can use Docker with VMWare instead of Hyper-V?  Your exact question is confusing, edit your question, and clarify it.](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-for-windows-w-vmware-installed/19011)

Comment: OK, I'm editing.

Comment: Done editing. Thanks for pointing the link. I've already read it, and the problem is precisely I described in my question, and it seems still doesn't have a solution. That's why I want to test inside a VM and confirm with that work.

Comment: So your asking if you can use Docker in a nested virtualization configuration?

Comment: If you consider docker as virtualization, yes.

Comment: It isn’t but at first I thought you were running in a different configuration.  I thought for sure Docker supported VMWare but Hyper-V was simply the default the hypervisor on Windows.

Comment: @Justalearner were you able to use docker from your 'Another Windows VM' (connecting to docker host on 'Ubuntu 18.04 LTS') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, docker containers will run in a VM, because Docker containers are only Linux processes. No virtualization involved.

AFAIK the "virtualization" required to run Docker containers in Windows is due to the "Docker machine" that emulates a Linux to run the containers, but if you use a plain Linux VM you don't need that.