# Configuring network for SQL-Server as a docker image on Ubuntu guest under Windows 10 host

Tags: windows-10, docker, vmware-workstation, ubuntu-18.04

I'd like to use my `Ubuntu` installation that hosts the `SQL-Server` that runs as a `docker` image as a test-machine for development. It runs as guest system under `VMware` that runs on `Window-10`. It's the same setup as here: [Does docker work correctly in a Ubuntu guest virtual machine of VMware Workstation?](https://superuser.com/questions/1386806/does-docker-work-correctly-in-a-ubuntu-guest-virtual-machine-of-vmware-workstati)

What stops from using it, is the connection from the host that I cannot establish.

So, my question is: do I have to configure some firewalls inside the guest or on the host to make it work? I tried every possible IP that I could find with `ipconfig /all` and `ip a` and `ip p` on Ubuntu, but without luck. I'm currently using a NAT connection, but I can change it to briged or anything else that would help.

Comment: SQLServer needs to be configured to use TCP\IP connections in SQL Configuration Manager. have you enabled those protocols for the server instances you wish to connect to, and then restarted the service?

Comment: @FrankThomas nope, I haven't as I didn't know I should, but I'll give it a try.